# Tracing bitcoin cash address to bitcoin address

Tags: bitcoin-cash

Given a bitcoin cash address that inherited deposit from main bitcoin , 
Is it possible to trace the bitcoin cash address back to bitcoin address ?

Answer (score 1):

You can look up the related transactions for the BCC address at blockdozer.com